# Java MessagePack null check

Tags: java, null, msgpack

I am trying to get familar with [Messagepack for Java](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java).

I get the data via Mqtt. If the variable is not `null` everything is fine but the variable can also be `null` and in this case I will get this Exception: `Expected Int, but got Nil (c0)`

```
MessageUnpacker unpacker = MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(m.getPayload());
int someInt              = unpacker.unpackInt();
String someString        = unpacker.unpackString();
```

So far I was not able to figure out how to get `NULL` back
I want to avoid to use TRY/CATCH so currently I am using this way

```
int someInt = unpacker.getNextFormat().equals("NIL") ? unpacker.unpackInt() : null;
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: It should rather be the reverse, no ? `Integer einInt = unpacker.getNextFormat().equals("NIL") ? null : unpacker.unpackInt();` `int` cannot receive null value.

Comment: of course you are right, thx for the heads up :)

Comment: Please make sure all answer, questions and comment left on Stackoverflow are in English. That also includes variable names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I looked the javadoc of `MessageUnpacker` and it doesn't seem provide a better way.

The example code is very close of your way :

```
 MessageUnpacker unpacker = MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(...);
 while(unpacker.hasNext()) {
     MessageFormat f = unpacker.getNextFormat();
     switch(f) {
         case MessageFormat.POSFIXINT:
         case MessageFormat.INT8:
         case MessageFormat.UINT8: {
            int v = unpacker.unpackInt();
            break;
         }
         case MessageFormat.STRING: {
            String v = unpacker.unpackString();
            break;
         }
         // ...
   }
 }
```

So I think that you are in the good path.
But if you repeat this retrieval multiple times(and it is very likely), you could introduce utility methods that does the job for you.

For example for `unpackInt()` :

```
public Integer unpackIntOrNull (MessageUnpacker unpacker){
    return unpacker.getNextFormat() == MessageFormat.INT8 ?
           unpacker.unpackInt() : null; 
}
```

And now, it is very straight to unpack elements :

```
Integer einInt = unpackIntOrNull(unpacker);
Integer einAndereInt = unpackIntOrNull(unpacker);
...
```

Comment: Thx for the answer

Looks like the .toString() is required

`unpacker.getNextFormat().toString().equals("NIL")`

Comment: Yes because you don't use the `MessageFormat` enum class but a String : `"NIL"` that you compare with the `toString()` representation of the the enum value.  I edited to show how avoid it. It is like in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

`MessageUnpacker` has a method named `tryUnpackNil`. If the next byte is a nil value, this method reads it and returns `true`, otherwise reads nothing and returns `false`.

This can be used to skip over nil values, and unpack non-nil values with e.g.:

```
final MessageUnpacker unpacker = MessagePack.newDefaultUnpacker(data);
final Integer value = unpacker.tryUnpackNil() ? null : unpacker.unpackInt();
```